# Why does Mysql Server Communicate with Client via Listen Socket?

Tags: java, mysql, sockets, tcp

Generally ,when a server accepts a TCP request in the first time ,it will get a new socket from operation system for subsequent communications .
For example ,the relevant function is `Socket java.net.ServerSocket.accept()` in java .
But notice what I see when I Use `netstat -anp|grep mysql` command. All the mysql communication sockets are using the 3306 port .

[image: netstat]

How to explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A TCP server will get a new *socket* from `accept()`, but the local *port* of that socket is the same as the listening port's, and that is what you are seeing.

Comment: You're right, that's a new question, but you need to read a network programming tutorial, or at least look up `socket(), bind(), listen(), accept()` for yourself.